# QTranslator strange behavior

Tags: qt, user-interface

I develop a program on MacOS using QT5.1.1 and I started to use the translation tools in order to translate my program to French (for the moment). I use the code below to install the `.qm` file :

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("/path_to_qm_file");
a.installTranslator(&translator);
```

Using the English file I've got the `About` and `Preferences` sub-menu which automatically goes in the `Joker` menu like that :

[image: correct behavior]

And when I load the French file `About` and `Preferences` go to the `File` menu :

[image: incorrect 1] [image]

How to make Qt understand that I want the first behavior to be the only one it should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to automatic deduction of `QAction` menu roles. The deduction works for English text, but not for French, especially that you're using the wrong translation of Properties (not the one from Apple's HIG). You need to explicitly set the menu role of your `Preferences` action to `QAction::PreferencesRole` - using `QAction::setMenuRole`. That will solve the problem.